# Creating a Subfolder for mobile project

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mobile, subdirectory

I have a website `www.mysite.com`. I created a mobile site for the same which is `mobile.mysite.com`.

Now the problem is I want to move the mobile and make it accessible via `www.mysite.com/m/`.

I am working in Codeigniter framework. If I have to do it so, then what things should I take care of? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create a sub-domain of your site `www.mysite.com` and name it as **"m"**. Shift all the folders and files of your mobile site into **"m"**. Now `www.mysite.com/m` would be accessible.

***Note:**  Don't crate sub folder in your main site.it wont work.you have to make sub-domain.

Comment: Ok. But the problem is that we have created wildcard subdomain *.mysite.com  to www.mysite.com  .  Also in .htacess I have written rule that if something like www.mysite.com/paris comes it will re-written to paris.mysite.com. So when  www.mysite.com/m comes it will be m.mysite.com. So how can I achieve that if its www.mysite.com/m it should not go to m.mysite.com. Something related to .htacess regex ??